# Boolean switch with comma vs or

Tags: go, switch-statement

I know that in Go, you can switch with conditions as the case statements like this:

```
func ctypeAlpha(b byte) bool {
    return (b >= 'a' && b <= 'z') || (b >= 'A' && b <= 'Z')
}

switch {
case ctypeAlpha(mysql[i]):
    ...
case mysql[i] == '"' || mysql[i] == '\'' || mysql[i] == '`':
    ...
```

But in learning that cases break implicitly, and that to have multiple matches execute the same code, you can use commas like this

```
switch {
case ctypeAlpha(mysql[i]):
    ...
case mysql[i] == '"', mysql[i] == '\'', mysql[i] == '`':
    ...
```

Personal opinions aside, which is preferred for performance?

Comment: On hold for opinion-based? I almost literally said in the last sentence "personal opinions aside, which is preferred for performance?"

Comment: it's not too late to edit the question to say actually that and it can get reopened

Comment: @Huangism that's fair, I've updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the above. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func isAlpha(b byte) bool {
    return (b >= 'a' && b <= 'z') || (b >= 'A' && b <= 'Z')
}

func isPunct(b byte) bool {
    return b == '"' || b == '\'' || b == '`'
}

func main() {
    i := 1
    mysql := make([]byte, i+1)
    mysql[i] = 'A'

    switch b := mysql[i]; {
    case isAlpha(b):
        fmt.Printf("isAlpha(%c)\n", b)
    case isPunct(b):
        fmt.Printf("isPunct(%c\n", b)
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/9SVWBExm9Xj

Output:

```
isAlpha(A)
```

Note:

```
-gcflags='-m'

inlining call to isAlpha
inlining call to isPunct
```

Comment: Yes, I should have prefaced that, this particular case is mixed in with other cases that need the boolean-ness, like `case ctypeAlpha(mysql[i]):` is also in this switch earlier in the statement in the actual code

Comment: It's been updated

Comment: Nice and clean, I didn't know about the declaring in the switch syntax, that's definitely useful, thank you!